# Prev and Next link for splitting single post into multiple pages

Tags: pagination

I have pagination on my site like this:

> Pages 1 2  3 4

… and so on. I am doing this by adding `<--nextpage-->` where i want to split my long pages into multiple pages.

I want to add previous and next links to the page numbers that looks like this:

> Prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 Next

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`wp_link_pages` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages)

```
<?php $args = array(
    'before'           => '<p>' . __('Pages:'),
    'after'            => '</p>',
    'link_before'      => '',
    'link_after'       => '',
    'next_or_number'   => 'number',
    'nextpagelink'     => __('Next page'),
    'previouspagelink' => __('Previous page'),
    'pagelink'         => '%',
    'echo'             => 1
);

wp_link_pages( $args );  ?>
```